# Attacks on "signatures" of the form sha256(message || secret)?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, sha256

I am testing an application that generates signatures in the following way

```
signature = sha256(message || shared_secret)
```

I know that if the signature was constructed with the message appended to the shared secret (i.e. `signature = sha256(shared_secret || message)`), this would be vulnerable to a [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack), but that does not seem applicable here.

Is this way to generate signatures vulnerable? I do think it's a bad idea anyway to use a hash function instead of HMAC to generate signatures, but I'd like to know if this is vulnerable to particular kinds of attacks.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2669/991 ​ ​

Comment: A HMAC has a single additional hash over a slightly altered key (and the result of this can be buffered if the key is reused), but it doesn't use any other *primitives* than a hash function. So the part of your question "to use a hash function instead of a HMAC" is a bit strange; if you use a HMAC you're basically using a hash as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code):

> The alternative, appending the key using MAC = H(message ∥ key), suffers from the problem that an attacker who can find collision in the (unkeyed) hash function has a collision in the MAC (as two messages m1 and m2 yielding the same hash will provide the same start condition to the hash function before the appended key is hashed, hence the final hash will be the same).